# htaccess for multiple subdomains from folders

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I am dealing with following problem:

I have one main domain "example.com" and multiple subdomains:

```
one.example.com
two.example.com
three.example.com
```

etc. on server.

I have content for this subdomains in folders:

```
./one/    -> one.example.com
./two/    -> two.example.com
./three/  -> three.example.com
```

etc.

So to serve content from these folders to subdomains, I use following htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^one.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/one/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  /one/$1  [L]
```

It works fine, but my content for subdomains is also accessable from URL:

```
one.example.com/one/my-content
```

such as

```
one.example.com/my-content
```

etc. So it is duplicite.

This is one problem I need to solve.

Second is, that content for example.com is accessable from

```
whatever.example.com
(a.example.com, b.example.com etc.)
```

so again duplicite.

So my question is: how to redirect/disable URLs that are creating duplicite?

Thanks a lot, I've tried a lot of versions of code, but with no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by redirecting all requests to a subdomain to that folder and all requests to the base domain to another, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /one$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^two\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /two$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.*) /zero$1
```

It seems to work, but I'm having my URL modified on the browser too. How do I avoid this from happening?

Comment: You should not answer the question and ask a follow up question at the same time.  Your follow up question likely will not get seen or answered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @psubsee2003. I'll properly post another question.

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue, you can add a rule, that redirects any requests to that folder and withing that directory to a page that does not exists (so that it throuws a 404 error)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^one/
RewriteRule . /notexists.html [L]
```

For your second issue, this should not happen since when you ask for a.example.com/folder/file.html it gets redirected internaly to a.example.com/a/folder/file.html (there is no way to get the content in the parent directory of 'a' )

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was trying to use your code, but with no result. I forget to mention, that I use dynamic creating of subdomains (DNS record * in CNAME) and maybe that is the problem, because, sometimes it behave wierd as I have no experience with this...